# get profile items from array in mikepenz material drawer

Tags: android, arrays, navigation-drawer, profile, materialdrawer

as you see there are some sample profile items that are bind to drawer for test(it's made from `IProfile`),but i want to get them from `arraylist<user>`

this is sample code:

```
final IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(LoginActivity.loggedInUser.get(0).getMobile()+"").withEmail(LoginActivity.loggedInUser.get(0).getResponse()).withIdentifier(100);
    final IProfile profile2 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Bernat Borras").withEmail("alorma@github.com").withIdentifier(101);
    final IProfile profile3 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Max Muster").withEmail("max.mustermann@gmail.com").withIdentifier(102);
    final IProfile profile4 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Felix House").withEmail("felix.house@gmail.com").withIdentifier(103);
    final IProfile profile5 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mr. X").withEmail("mister.x.super@gmail.com").withIdentifier(104);
    final IProfile profile6 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Batman").withEmail("batman@gmail.com").withIdentifier(105);
```

that this profiles will add to `accountHeader` and `addProfiles(profile,profile1,...);` method.

but i want to set the profile items from an array...
i am trying to make An `IProfile` Array from my users:

like getting profiles this way:

```
 if(!Arrays.userCars.isEmpty()) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= Arrays.userCars.size(); i++) {
        Arrays.profiles.add(new ProfileDrawerItem()
          .withName(Arrays.userCars.get(i).getName())
          .withEmail(Arrays.userCars.get(i).getCarCompany().toString())
          .withIdentifier(103 + i));
    
      }
    }
```

but how is possible to get this items from `profiles` Array and use in `addProfiles()` method?
remember that this method is from library and I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

The MaterialDrawer library exposes a function to configure the profiles as `vararg` arguments, so it's more convenient to use.

In case you want to provide items as `array` you can use the `*` (spread operator) in Kotlin for example.

```
val myArray = arrayOf(profile, profile2, profile3)
addProfiles(*myArray)
```